# import com.qualcomm.QCAR.QCAR; not resolved

Tags: android, vuforia

I am trying to run the sample application of vuforia. But when i run it in eclipse it gives the error `import com.qualcomm.QCAR.QCAR; not resolved`.
I googled it, and tried the option different people suggested.

- Adding the `qcar.jar` in buildpath.
- Adding PATH avironment

Comment: try make a libs folder in your project, put it there and REMOVE it from buildpath

Comment: I faced the same problem. The problem was with setting the environment variable of QCAR. Test it one more time and check the path. It will work.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

the name of the library has change from Qcar.jar to vuforia.jar  . once you download that add it to the java build path and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

1) project(rightclick)-buildpath-configure build path-java build path - library-add external jar-QCAR.jar

2) clean - build ndk -refresh - run it.